# jquery update textboxes based on checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, textbox

I need to update the value on an unknown number of textboxes based on their corresponding checkboxes.

```
<input type="text" id="text0" />
<input type="checkbox" id="ckval1" class="checkvaloare" value="0" />
<input type="text" id="text1" class="ckval1" />
<br />
<div id="div"></div>

$("#text0").on("keyup change", function () {
    qty = $(this).val();
    if (qty === "") {
        qty = 0;
    }
    if ($('#ckval1').is(":checked")) {
        $(".ckval1").val(qty);
    } else {
        $(".ckval1").val(0);
    }
});

$('#ckval1').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".ckval1").val(qty);
    } else {
        $(".ckval1").val(0);

    }
});
```

What I would like to have is something like this:
each time #text0 changes its value 
for each checkbox with **id**=RANDOM_SOMETHING
if the checkbox is checked
then the textbox with the **class**=RANDOM_SOMETHING gets the value of #text0
else (if the textbox is not checked) the textbox with the **class**=RANDOM_SOMETHING gets the value 0

If it happens that a checkbox is checked but there is no corresponding textbox, then I don't need that checkbox.

The fiddle with what works: http://jsfiddle.net/flish/ae629/11/
The fiddle with what doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/flish/ae629/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this,

```
$("#text0").on("keyup change", function () {
    update();
});

$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
    update();
});

function update() {
    var value = $("#text0").val();

    $("input[type=text]").not("#text0").each(function () {
        if (($(this).prev().is(":checked"))) {
            $(this).val(value);
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).val(0);
        }
    });

}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ae629/19/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the $("#text0").on("keyup change here", function () {

```
ids = [];
$('.checkvaloare').each(function () {
    ids.push(this.id);
});

$("#text0").on("keyup", function () {
    qty = $(this).val();
    if (qty === "") {
        qty = 0;
    }
    if ($('#ckval1').is(":checked")) {
        $(".ckval1").val(qty);
    } else {
        $(".ckval1").val(0);
    }

});

$("checkbox").click(function () {
    $.each(ids, function (index, value) {
        if ($("checkbox").attr("id") === value) {
            if ($('this').is(":checked")) {
                if ($("text").attr("class") === value) {
                    $('this').val(qty);
                } else {
                    $('this').val(0);
                }
            }

        }
    });
});
```

Check out demo here http://jsfiddle.net/flish/ae629/12/